# Contextual Classes cannot override Table Head Colors Classes (.thead-dark/.thead-light)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am studying tables in Bootstrap 4.
I don't know why the background-color in table-light class is not applied. Is this because table-light cannot override the thead-dark? If it is true, can you tell me what makes thead-dark take priority over? If it is not what I think, please explain the reason behind it for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Contextual Classes</h2>
  <p>Contextual classes can be used to color the table, table rows or table cells. The classes that can be used are: .table-primary, .table-success, .table-info, .table-warning, .table-danger, .table-active, .table-secondary, .table-light and .table-dark:</p>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th class="table-light">Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default</td>
        <td>Defaultson</td>
        <td>def@somemail.com</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr class="table-primary">
        <td>Primary</td>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>joe@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-success">
        <td>Success</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-danger">
        <td>Danger</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-info">
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-warning">
        <td>Warning</td>
        <td>Refs</td>
        <td>bo@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-active">
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Activeson</td>
        <td>act@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-secondary">
        <td>Secondary</td>
        <td>Secondson</td>
        <td>sec@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-light">
        <td>Light</td>
        <td>Angie</td>
        <td>angie@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-dark text-dark">
        <td>Dark</td>
        <td>Bo</td>
        <td>bo@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body> <!-- source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_tables.asp -->
```

Problem:

[image]

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Answer (score 2):

This is how `.thead-light` is defined in the [Bootstrap stylesheet](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css).

```
.table .thead-light th {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-color: #dee2e6;
}
```

You see it targets `th` elements which are descendants of an element which has the `thead-light` class.

So when you apply the class to a `th` element, as you do in

```
<th class="table-light">Firstname</th>
```

you would need to target

```
th.thead-light {
   /* CSS */
}
```

Otherwise the specificity of `.table-dark > th` will override that of `<th class="table-light">`

```
.table-dark,
.table-dark > th, /* <<< This rule */
.table-dark > td {
  background-color: #c6c8ca;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `bootstrap.css` this rule:

```
.table .thead-dark th {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212529;
  border-color: #32383e;
}
```

is defined **after** this rule:

```
.table-light,
.table-light > th,
.table-light > td {
  background-color: #fdfdfe;
}
```

### But most importantly:

When you use the [CSS Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) and compare this: 
`th.table-light` (which is what's actually being used here) to this `.table .thead-dark th`, you'll see that the latter has higher specificity and thus wins regardless.

### Conclusion:

In order for a css rule to "win" (i.e. take precedence) it must either have higher specificity than a competing css rule OR if the specificity is the same (which is *not* the case here), it must be listed *after* the competing css rule.

Also note:

Using the `!important` flag (as some people might suggest) should only be reserved for quick testing and should **not** be used as a permanent solution. (because otherwise, it would result in a nightmare for maintenance)

Comment: He applied .table-light to th directly. So its not because after/before definition. Just .table .thead-dark th has higher priority then .table-light

Comment: @AlexeyAvdeyev In this particular case `.table .thead-dark th` has a higher specificity. That is correct. But if both had the exact same specificity, the last defined rule would win.